# Powershell script to convert comma separated values into rows and output as new CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with cells containing comma separated values .I am trying to split comma separated values into rows . I put examples below of input and desired output

This is the CSV file

```
Name |      Role  
John |      physics,chemistry  
Ram  |      chemistry ,maths
```

This is how I would the data after processing

```
- Name | Role 

- John | Physics  

- John | Chemistry

- Ram  | Chemistry

- Ram  | Maths
```

Comment: Please show us the REAL first three lines of the input csv file, not something you formatted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In utf-8 csv standard version the rows would appear like this when viewed as plain text

> Name Role
>   John,"physics,chemistry"
>   Ram,"chemistry ,maths"
>   Bob,math"
>   Mary,"physics,chemistry,maths"

Then the following code should work

```
$csvFilePath = "My.csv"

$table=@()
$csv= import-csv $csvFilePath
foreach($row in $csv){
    if($row.Role -like "*,*"){
        $roles=$row.Role.split(",")
        foreach($role in $roles){
            $table+=[pscustomobject]@{
                Name=$row.name
                Role=$role.trim()
             }
        }
    }
    else{
    $table+=$row
    }
}
```

Which would produce

> Name Role
>
> ---
>
> John physics
>   John chemistry
>   Ram  chemistry
>   Ram  maths
>   Bob  maths
>   Mary physics
>   Mary chemistry 
>   Mary maths

Comment: If the file name changes everyday based on datetimestamp , any idea how to set the csvfilepath please

Comment: Do you have an example of the filenames or file paths?  Are they the only things in the folder. You can do it with get-date 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7

Comment: Also please mark the answer as useful if it worked for you, so it can be ranked towards top answer.

Comment: Hi Zach , when I debug the code , $table has perfectly split all the values ,but not sure how to output this $table to new CSV file with new split data , can you please tell me ,how to do this ?

Comment: Not sure how to mark this answer as useful ,do not have the reputation yet

Comment: Ha,ha yea. I know it took me days to get enough rep to comment on things....

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
$details= Import-Csv -Path "sample.csv"
    foreach ($line in $details){
        $splitRole= ($line.Role).Split(",")
        foreach($role in $splitRole){

        Write-host $line.Name $role

    }
}
```

Comment: CSV  Name Role
John physics,chemistry
Ram chemistry ,maths

Comment: Please make it as answer, if you found the solution

Comment: This code only answer could be improved by adding some explanation of how and why it works, and if the image is necessary it shouldn't be indented because that causes it to show up as code rather than as an image.

Answer (score 0):

The following script runs smoothly in `PowerShell -version 2` (originally tagged [powershell-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-2.0)) or above:

```
$CsvObject = @'
Name|Role
John|physics,chemistry
Ram|chemistry,maths
Joe|biology
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'
$CsvObjectNew = foreach ($CsvLine in $CsvObject ) {
    $CsvLine.Role -split ',' | ForEach-Object {
        ### PowerShell -version 2.0 or above
        New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Name = $CsvLine.Name
            Role = $_
        }
    }
}
$CsvObjectNew |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
'--- or ---'
($CsvObjectNew |
    ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation |
        Out-String ) -replace '"'
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\61941506.ps1`

> ```
> "Name"|"Role"
> "John"|"physics"
> "John"|"chemistry"
> "Ram"|"chemistry"
> "Ram"|"maths"
> "Joe"|"biology"
> --- or ---
> Name|Role
> John|physics
> John|chemistry
> Ram|chemistry
> Ram|maths
> Joe|biology
> ```

In  `PowerShell -version 3` or above, you could shorten the

```
        New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
            Name = $CsvLine.Name
            Role = $_
        }
```

code snippet using `[PSCustomObject]` [type accelerator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) as follows:

```
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $CsvLine.Name
        Role = $_
    }
```